# Use Angular's interpolation for data-tippy-content

Tags: angular, typescript, tippyjs

I'm working on an **Angular** project and have **tippy.js** working fine ( https://atomiks.github.io ).

The problem is that I need to fill the tooltips with some JSON information that I could place with Angular's interpolation, but the following error shows up:
"Can't bind to 'tippy-content' since it isn't a known property of 'div'."

```html
<div data-tippy-content="{{top.description}}" data-tippy-placement="right" class="layout-tops-photos theme-tops-photos theme-hover js-tippy"></div>
```

Is there a way to make it work with interpolation? If not, is there another way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use attribute binding syntax

```
<div attr.data-tippy-content="{{top.description}}" data-tippy-placement="right" class="layout-tops-photos theme-tops-photos theme-hover js-tippy"></div>
```

Comment: Not working in my case


https://stackblitz.com/edit/hello-angular-6-blpzc8?file=src/app/app.component.html